# Wordpress: Using Custom Post Type for image list of Product

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a Wordpress-blog with gift ideas where I write text based articles. I recently discovered Custom Post types which I believe is the solution to an feature I want to create.

What I want:

- Be able to tag each custom post using the normal "Categories" and "Tags".
- Create a 3x3 matrix with product images (custom posts) to be shown on top of each Category-view or Tag-view (followed by the typical article list in the category or tag).

Example:

- Lets say I have a category "Gifts for mom" and tags "Pink", "Cheap"
- In the category "Gifts for mom" I have 10 text articles (normal posts) discussing the difficulties of buying gifts for your mom
- I create nine custom posts, each is a **specific** gift (e.g. A pink hairbrush). I want to place them in the Category "Gifts for mom" and tag them with "Pink".
- When I view myrandomgiftblogname.com/category/gifts-for-mom I want to be able to get a view:

Gifts for mom 
Product Product Product 
 
Product Product Product
 
Product Product Product

Articles:
- This awesome article
- That awesome article
- Etc

I assume this is possible but don't really know where to begin. Could you point me in the right direction? Which Plugins do I need? Do I need to do any programming myself (or just plugin configuration)? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description is a bit broad, hence a bit broad answer.

Two things are needed:

#### 1) A plugin to create the Custom Post Type.

It is considered best practice to let CPT's in Plugin territory. So you can swap designs and preserve your CPT functionality. In reality, you are asking for future problems letting this be handled by the theme.

Create [your own plugin](http://www.doitwithwp.com/create-functions-plugin/), which would contain a [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and any extra configs.

Use an existent plugin, like [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/).
*Its Custom Fields features are quite handy as well.*

> Allows users to create custom content types (also known as post types) and standardized custom fields for each, including dropdowns, checkboxes, and images.

#### 2) Learn how to use and customize WordPress Templates

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates
> Templates are the files which control how your WordPress site will be displayed on the Web. These files draw information from your WordPress MySQL database and generate the HTML code which is sent to the web browser. Through its powerful Theme system, WordPress allows you to define as few or as many Templates as you like all under one Theme. Each of these Template files can be configured for use under specific situations.

Comment: It is quite difficult to explain what it is exactly what I need but I guess this is as close as I can get to an answer to that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Add a new `Page` for each category with the exact same name as the category.
2. In the `Images` menu attach to each of those pages the images you want.
3. In your script query for a page with a name identical to the current category, and pull all of its attachments